# Can I, and should I, force the contents of DGV cells to be null?

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, datagridview

I'm saving values entered in a DGV to a List`<T`>; they are decimal values or nothing (empty). If empty, I want them to be viewed as null, so that my helper function will see those empty vals as 0. But this line here:

```
rrsr.DuckbillRate = Convert.ToDecimal(GetValAtColRow(colNumber, rowNumber));
```

...sometimes fails with "Input string not in a correct format" (when it fails, the value it's trying to convert is a string.empty):

Here are my helper functions to get the cell values, so that I can save them in my List`<T`>, and restore/repopulate the cells from the contents of those records stored in the List`<T`>:

```
private string GetValAtColRow(int colNum, int rowNum)
{
 DataGridViewRow desiredRow = dataGridViewPlatypi.Rows[rowNum];
 return (desiredRow.Cells[colNum].Value ?? 0).ToString(); 
}

private void SetValAtColRow(int colNum, int rowNum, string val)
{
 string convertedVal = val;
 // If the value is 0, I want to display an empty cell (nothing)
 if (convertedVal.Equals("0"))
 {
  convertedVal = string.Empty;
 }
 DataGridViewRow desiredRow = dataGridViewPlatypi.Rows[rowNum];
 desiredRow.Cells[colNum].Value = convertedVal;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parsing is becoming wrong somewhere...

Input string not in a correct format error usually comes when parsing is not done correctly...

Regarding other issue...try to do like this>>>

```
string a =  dataGridViewPlatypi.Rows[rowNum].Cells[colNum].Value.toString()

if(a=="")
{
.
.
//further things
}
```

Comment: Yeah bro...Syntax might be wrong...semicolun also missing...but i think direction is write...

Comment: @freelancer: Thanks, I knew there must be a cleaner/more direct way to access the column and row in one line as you do above. As for whether this actually helps my problem, though, I won't know until Monday.